# Automatically Copy Rows Between Worksheets to Last Row on Workbook Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying, for two weeks now, to write a code which will be able to do the following:
The first 21 rows of worksheet "Time Cards" are copied and inserted into the first blank row at the bottom of the same sheet "Time Cards." I also would like, once the rows are copied, the cell that houses the date of the selection that was just copied (at the bottom of the sheet) to be selected, so that the user does not have to scroll down 6500 rows.

The code would have to select sheet ("Time Cards"), copy selection C3:N23, and paste selection to the last and first blank row to the bottom of the sheets("Time Cards"). Then the cell (in the selection that was just pasted) that house the "date" has to be automatically selected (write code to search the range for "date"?). Once all that is done, I'd like a code, linked to a macro button, that the user can click to clear the data validations, so that only formulas remain in the newly pasted cells, and all the VLOOKUPS, and DATA VALIDATIONS have been cleared.

Please, can someone please please please help me write a code. I've really did a lot a research, tried several different approaches, and have not been able to make anything work. I'm not really proficient with VBA, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my first attempt:

```
Sub CopyInfo()

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheets("Time Cards").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select


    Sheets("TC-Start Here").Select
    Range("C5:N25").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("Time Cards").Select
    'Range("C5:N25").Select
    Selection.Insert

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "The Data has been successfully Copied"

End Sub
```

Then I tried to select the last row and paste (2nd attempt):

```
Sub CopyInfo()

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheets("Time Cards").Select
    Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select


    Sheets("TC-Start Here").Select
    Range("C5:N25").Select
    Selection.Copy


    Sheets("Time Cards").Select
    Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheets("Time Cards").Select
    'Range("C5:N25").Select
    Selection.Insert

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "The Data has been successfully Copied"

End Sub
```

It doesn't seem to work and I could never get it to select the cell containing the date nor clear the validations.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what is not working, Dora. From there, we can tweak your attempts and help you better understand how to get what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for responding. i have revised my original explanation. Please refer to above.

Comment: Can you clarify about "it never works"? Also, it might help to add some sample data. Rather than selecting the ranges (sheet/cells), just work with them directly: `Sheets("TC-Start Here").Range("C5:N25").Copy`, `Sheets("Time Cards").cells(someRow,1).EntireRow.Insert` This is more efficient and helps to avoid potential errors with using `Activate`/`Select`

Comment: A few other things: if you want this to happen every time you open the workbook, then put it in your Workbook code (in the Editor) - use this: `Private Sub Workbook_Open() ...some code... End Sub`. As far as scrolling, can't they just use `Ctrl+[Down Arrow]` to get to the last row? scott's use of `select` does what you want, though. :)

Comment: You say you want all formulas to remain, but you also say you want all VLOOKUP's cleared.  Which is it?  And is it C3:N23 (in description), or C5:N25 (in your code) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, if not please clarify your question further

```
    Dim lrow as long
    lrow = sheets("time cards").range("C5").end(xlup).row + 1
    sheets("TC-Start Here").range("C5:N25").copy
    sheets("time cards").range("C" & lrow).pastespecial paste:=xlpastevalues, _
                                                        operation:=xlnone, _
                                                        skipblanks:=False, _
                                                        Transpose:=false
    sheets("time cards").range("C5").end(xlup).select
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried your code, and mixed in the ideas of Zairja (with using the workbook open versus the what i was doing),When i launch the application, the code does work, but I would like it to, every time the data from Sheets ("Time Cards") gets inserted, the existing data, from the previous session does not get erased, but shifted down. is there a way, through a loop, to make the pasted data not override but shift down any existing data in the cells?

Comment: And thank you everyone for helping me. I think i'm close to figuring it out will all your inputs.

Comment: @Dora To shift down, use `.insert` before `.pastespecial` (on same range), but keep in mind that it will affect formulas in shifted rows, which may or may not be desirable behavior. edit: this inserts the rows, then pastes the values in the inserted rows

Comment: Thank you so much Everyone. I got it to work. I still need a code to be able to clear the data validations after the Range("C5:N25") is pasted. I'm going to research that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyInfo()

    With Sheets("Time Cards")
         .Range("C5:N25").Copy .Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         .Cells(Rows.Count,3).End(xlUp).Select
    End With
    'need some info on exactly what should be cleared from the copied range...
    MsgBox "The Data has been successfully Copied"

End Sub
```